# How to choose the delimiters used by the WordDelimiterFilter in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to index words like `e-mail` as `email`, `e mail` and `e-mail` with Lucene 4.4.0.

Lucene's [`WordDelimiterFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html) should be ideal for this. However, it treats every(?) non-alphanumeric character as a delimiter. So, terms like `C++` are transformed to `C`, which is not what I want.

Is it therefore possible to customize the `WordDelimiterFilter` such that it uses my own specified delimiters?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly define the '+' and the other characters as alpha characters so that they are not filtered out, and they are considered in the search queries.

Follow the below steps for the customization

1) Under "index" and query" analyzers modify the WordDelimiterFilterFactory and add types="alphatypes.txt".

```
<filter catenateAll="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateWords="0" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="alphatypes.txt"/>
```

Set the other param as per your case

2)Then create the alphatypes.txt (or by any name that suits you) file with the following and place it in the same folder as the schema.xml file.

NOTE: for the # character we have to use the unicode value.

```
# A customized type mapping for WordDelimiterFilterFactory
# the allowable types are: LOWER, UPPER, ALPHA, DIGIT, ALPHANUM, SUBWORD_DELIM
#
# the default for any character without a mapping is always computed from
# Unicode character properties

+ => ALPHA
\u0023 => ALPHA
```

3) Reload the core, or restart Solr.

4) Re-index the data so that the missing characters are included in the index

Solr jira reference https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2059

Comment: Thank you so far. But I am actually using Lucene, so this approach is not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: @Phauly - You did tag [tag:solr], though. Anyway, all those settings are also available through the Lucene API. [See the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html).

Comment: @femtoRgon I have looked through the whole docs, but I did not find any information about custom delimiters. Which passage do you mean?